# How to cache a PDF in the Servlet's Context, itext

Tags: java, pdf, servlets, pdf-generation, itext

I would like to cache a PDF template in a servlet's context. Every time someone wants to generate a report the servlet will grab the template from the context, copy it then modify the copy with dynamic data. This will keep the application from hitting the hard drive every time a report is generated.

This is one way that I tried but does not seem to work. I get a null pointer error

```
RandomAccessFileOrArray pdfTemplate = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(
        context.getResourceAsStream("pathToPdf"));

context.setAttribute("pdftemplate", pdfTemplate);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have google searched this and cannot find any examples on the best way to code this.

Thanks for your time
Doug

Comment: Do you have several templates to load?

Comment: I was going to try and make it just one template. Some issues I am having with iText and copying imported pages might cause me to use more than one template

Comment: If you wouldn't like to load from IO, then you can create in memory if it is 20 or 30 templates. If it grows then you should consider it. As always says don't over design :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Some PDF Templates and stored them in the Servlets context and it works fine.